# Spring MVC Maven multi module controller is not working

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have spring maven multi module project, in that I have more modules, these modules consists of dao, domain, service, and controllers. I have separate application context XML file for each modules. Controllers in the modules are not working, but controllers present in the web module is working. I had given `@Controller` in the controller class, and `mvc:annotation-driven` and `context:component` scan tags in the spring application context file. Why is it not working?

Comment: How are the modules referenced? Do you have a separate maven project that is packaged as *.war and referencing the projects as dependencies? Can you confirm that all context files are loaded?

Comment: yes, all dependency jar files are loaded, i mapping the jar files from persistence.xml file through <jar-file> tag

Comment: I think we need a lot more information, like maybe context file(s), WAR/JAR packaging and deployment structures, and probably packages and maybe some of the controller code (at least the bits with the annotations on them). There are lots of reasons why your controllers are not being picked up.  Maybe the JARs are not in the classpath like you think they are.  Maybe the component scan is set to scan package `a.b.c`, but your controller is in `x.y.z`. Maybe the controllers are being created in a separate ApplicationContext. Too many factors to try to troubleshoot off virtually no info.